# how can i use a specific operator in a macro definition

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I would like to know if it is possible to use a specific operator in a macro definition

I have a macro where it works fine

It is as follows:

```
#define TestMacroDefine(i, ...) \
  Start->Client(i, __VA_ARGS__);
```

Example of use:

```
TestMacroDefine(pck->i, &pck->len);
```

As you can see I use the & operator, is there any way I can migrate this operator to the macro definition?

do something like:

```
#define TestMacroDefine(i, ...) \
      Start->Client(i, &__VA_ARGS__);
```

Comment: Why not *try it*? Try your proposed macro, and tell the compiler to stop after preprocessing so you can see the resulting code that will be fed into the compiler.

Comment: As for the more generic question of "can I use operator in a macro", the answer is yes. You're already using two operators in your macro: The structure pointer dereference and access operator `->` and the function call operator `()`. So your title isn't really a short description or summary of the actual question or problem you ask about.

Comment: What is the question? You have an idea, what's wrong with it? Did you get any errors from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes (leave out the last `;` of the macro though):

```
#define TestMacroDefine(i, ...) Start->Client(i, &__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    TestMacroDefine(pck->i, pck->len);
}
```

will expand to what you wanted:

```
$ cpp 1.c
...
int main() {
 Start->Client(pck->i, &pck->len);
}
```

Comment: This works, just a question if I have more than one var in the function how could I apply the `&` operator to all vars?

Comment: No, it will only work for the first variadic argument.  If you name the arguments then you of course specify the & for each of those.